# Use increment variable "i" in for loop and pass the relevant value from constructor function

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

Couldn't wrap my head around this. Code sample as follow. The goal is to pass `images/preview-1.png`, `images/preview-2.png`, `images/preview-3.png` to `$('.element:eq(0)')`, `$('.element:eq(1)')` and `$('.element:eq(2)')`

```
function Project(url){
  this.url = url;
}

var project1 = new Project("images/preview-1.png");
var project2 = new Project("images/preview-2.png");
var project3 = new Project("images/preview-3.png");

for(i=0; i<2; i++){
  $('.element:eq(' + i + ')').attr("srcset", "____");
}
```

What should we put in `"____"`?
Tried to concatenate the i variable but failed.

Comment: Thanks guys! You unanimously point to .each/forEach(). I will take a good look into it. Still a noob now :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible:

```
$('.element').each(function(i, el) {
    $(this).attr('srcset', 'images/preview-'+(i+1)+'.png');
});
```

If you need to use the `Project` constructor then you may try this:

```
$('.element').each(function(i, el) {
    var project = new Project('images/preview-'+(i+1)+'.png');
    $(this).attr('srcset', project.url);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That seems quite verbose without much reason. If you're trying to set those attributes to different items in the collection, why not make an array of images and then just iterate over it?

```
const imgSrcs = [
  'images/preview-1.png',
  'images/preview-2.png',
  'images/preview-3.png',
];
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');
imgSrcs.forEach((src, i) => {
  elements[i].setAttribute('srcset', src);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code works for you. If no.of Project instances are variable then it's a good idea to keep them in an array and work on them.

```
function Project(url){
    this.url = url;
}

var projects = [
    new Project("images/preview-1.png"),
    new Project("images/preview-2.png"),
    new Project("images/preview-3.png")
];

projects.forEach(function(eachProject, loopIndex) {
    $('.element:eq(' + loopIndex + ')').attr("src", eachProject.url);
});
```